# Forwarding a mail as a fax using Applescript and Mail

Tags: mail.app, applescript, fax

I am using the Mac's fax function and that works just great. I would, however, like to make an Applescript that gets called from a Mail rule. For example, when the Subject is something like: "FAX:12345679", the rule should take the fax number from the subject and use it to fax the attachment via the fax-modem printer.

Is this possible?

Comment: Would you be using the same number, or set of phone numbers every time?

Comment: Ideally the number should be taken from the Subject.

Comment: I'll see if I can can come up with something...

Comment: WOW That would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, I don't think that there is a way to use AppleScript with the Mac fax function.  I am able to create a script which grabs attachments, but I can't find a way to hook into the fax function, without using a 3rd party faxing app.  Sorry, I thought there was a way.